# DataTemplate not loading in pivot windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to display different layouts in pivot items in a wp8.1 app (UNIAPP ). Ideally I would like to load different pages but since I could figure this out, I thought I'd try with the basics first as I'd use this before but for some reason I can't get this to work.

My pivot items are loaded dynamically based on the provided ViewModel

```
 <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <controls:DataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    </controls:DataTemplateSelector>
   /DataTemplate>
 </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

My resources are defined as follows within the same xaml page

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyApp.ViewModel.PIDetailsVM">
        <Button Content="test" Foreground="White"></Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyApp.ViewModel.PIListVM">
        <Button Content="test" Foreground="White"></Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

My DataTemplateSelector is defined as follows:

```
public class DataTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
  protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, 
  object newContent)
  {
    ContentTemplate = this.FindResource<DataTemplate>(newContent.GetType
    ().FullName);
  }
}
```

It is being triggered whenever I go to a new pivot item, but the ContentTemplate is always null.

The `newContent.GetType().FullName` returns the relevant viewmodel name which I can see being displayed in the relevant pivot.

One thing I noticed is that the DataTemplateSelector class (this) has no resources when I check it via this.Resources.count(), so it's obviously not finding them but how do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

My DataTemplates are not getting loaded in my Pivot Items. There is obviously a problem with the .NET IDE as whenever I add or remove a  from Content="{Binding}" it displays the button within the pivot item but that's within the IDE. Unfortunately, at run-time, it just displays the name of my viewmodel.

Thought the behaviour is erratic in the IDE, the fact that the button from my DataTemplate is displaying when messing around with the `Content="{Binding<space>"` would make you think that the code and xaml are correct but it's definitely not working at run-time.

Any idea what's wrong why my DataTemplates are not displaying in pivot item?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and clarify what exactly is your question/problem now after all?

Comment: Just clarified the post. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer. By this I mean that I did find a work-around to my problem but I did not resolve the issue itself.

My DataTemplateSelector which gets triggered whenever the pivot changes call a extension function called FindResource:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static T FindResource<T>(this DependencyObject initial, 
    string key) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject current = initial;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current is FrameworkElement)
            {
                if ((current as FrameworkElement).Resources.
                     ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    return (T)(current as FrameworkElement).Resources[key];
                }
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }

        if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)Application.Current.Resources[key];
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

For some strange reason, Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) does not like having the data templates in  while it is not a problem in WP8/WP8.1 Silverlight.

As mentioned, this is unstable in the IDE where it sometimes displays the DataTemplate, and sometimes it doesn't depending on whether or not I add a space after the Binding keyword to the `Content="{Binding}"`. One thing for sure is that it never works at run-time, well not at least not with the above code.

`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current)` always returns `null` no matter what. I've checked at debug time if I somehow could access the resources, but to no avail.

How did I fix it? Well, I moved my data templates to a resource dictionary

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyApp.ViewModel.PIDetailsVM">
    <Button Content="test" Foreground="White"></Button>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyApp.ViewModel.PIListVM">
    <Button Content="test" Foreground="White"></Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

The second I did this, the second part of my FindResources kicks in since the Current object is always null, no matter what

```
if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    return (T)Application.Current.Resources[key];
  }
```

and it finds the relevant DataTemplate and displays it accordingly in my pivot control based on the relevant PivotItem ViewModel.

Now, I'm not out of the woods yet as I have no idea if binding to the relevant viewmodel will work but that's a whole other story!

If anyone knows why `DataTemplate` cannot be found when defined in Pages.Resources or Grid.Resources, please update the post as I'd love to know why.

Thanks.